# how to increase the performance in android app?

Tags: android, performance

I am new to the android application development, I designed an app, which is completely based on `WebView` displaying, now I observed that the performance is too slow, Can any one give some suggestions that how can I increase the app performance?

Thanks,
Nikil.l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store some of the html files locally.

Else you should write an native android application for more performance.